# We can add custom field in opencart product page?

Tags: php, module, opencart, opencart2.x

Please info me we can add custom field in product page without change Opencart core file. As like in WordPress we can add `post_meta` using `hook` in `functions.php` file.

If Add Custom options after add new filter on front end side. display product only this product options are selected.

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Log into your OpenCart admin panel.
2. Navigate to Sales-> Customers-> Custom Fields section:
3. Press the Add New blue button located in the top right of the page:
4. Fill in the necessary fields:

   > Custom Field Name – the title of a new field that will appear on the registration page.
   >
   > Location – this option allows to choose either the Account or the Address section for the custom field to appear on.
   >
   > Type – here you can assign any of the 4 available types to your custom field (Choose, Input, File, Date). This type affects the
   >   look and the character of the new field. If you select one of the
   >   ‘choose’ options (checkbox, radio or select drop-down), you will
   >   have to create a new value in the Custom field option at the bottom.
   >   Click the add new button to create multiple values from which the
   >   user will be able to select (or pick multiple in the checkbox case):
   >
   > Customer Group – select the group of customers for which this field will be visible.
   >
   > Required – if you select this option, your customers will not be able to complete the registration without filling in the
   >   field.
   >
   > Status – here you can enable/disable the new field.
   >
   > Sort Order – the position of your custom field in relation to the existing fields.
5. Click the Save button in the top right:
6. View how the new custom field appears on your registration page on the site front end.

Source: [Here](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/opencart-2-x-how-to-add-custom-fields-to-contact-form.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for ans.. But i want to get option in product page not registration page.

Comment: You can do it using vqmod. It changed the code without changing the core files. It is a bit lengthy and tricky process. :)

Comment: If you have it's script for share with me...and one more if Upgrade Opencart "vqmod" code is remove or not.. Thanks so much. @ali Zia

Comment: I don't have the script with me. And if you ungrade opencart, it won't affect the vqmod. It would still exist. :)